# Identifing components' memory in the JVM

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory

We have a few teams running server components in one JVM.

When a memory issue arises, we need to know how much memory each component has taken (or who is to blame for the `OOME` :-) ).

Is there any general technique that can help identify each component's memory usage?

I'm aware of memory dumps and their analysis tools, but there are cases where the analysis is very complex because of complex graphs and such.
I was wondering if there are some advanced techniques like private heaps or efficient way to monitor each component memory.

Comment: What do you mean by "component"?

Comment: If your reference graph is very complex, that should be a warning sign.

Comment: In components I just mean different applicative parts of the application. @Kedar Mhaswade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a memory profiler like the one in Flight Recorder which is built in.

This can give you the break down of memory usage from the largest users.  I would work down this list to see where most of the memory is being retained.

Comment: Starting the VM with `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError ` is also quite useful, particularly if your memory leak is not easily reproducible.

Comment: @biziclop I also tend to increase the heap size, though I would reduce it for a smaller heap dump.